# Plotting a function of two variables and pointwise minimization

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

How can I get a 3d-plot the following function in MATLAB?

```
f(x,y)=log(1+ (min(x,y))^2/(4*y));
```

I want to create a 3d-plot of `f` as a function of `x` and `y`. `x` and `y` are non-negative so they can range from 0 to any positive number like 10.

I tried to plot this with `surf` and `meshgrid` but it didn't work since I have a pointwise minimization.

Comment: Thanks, you're still going to need to [edit] your question to include more details, what have you tried? What's your specific issue? What's some example input ranges and desired visuals? There are lots of questions already here, which along with the official documentation describe in detail how to use `plot3` or `surf` for instance, this is currently too broad

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have edited the question based on your comment. @Wolfie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, create x and y with meshgrid :

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(0:0.5:10,0:0.5:10);
```

then compute function and plot :

```
k(:,:,1)=x;
k(:,:,2)=y;
% because x and y are 2d matrices in meshgrid, I defined 3d matrix k to compute minimum in third dimension:
z=log((1+ (min(k,[],3)).^2)./(4*y));
surf(x,y,z)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Hadi, the last line shouldn't be surf(x,y,z)?!@Hadi